# Windows 2012 Server WinLogon error

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

I recently installed Windows 2012 and am having problems with two items.  RDP fails to connect after a short period of inactivity and after the initial system startup the console ctl-alt-del fails to respond.

The following error is issued to the event logs a couple of times a second:

```
Error: 4005, Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon
The Windows logon process has unexpectedly terminated.
```

Technet and various Google searches indicate:

- System resources are inadequate or unavailable.
- The Windows registry is corrupted.
- A service failed to start.

So, I'm guessing this relates to lsass.exe somehow, but can't figure out what or indeed if that is related.

Comment: Test with a clean user without gpo. Give us more eventlog error

Comment: I'll try a new user tomorrow, I'll post the results.  As for more of the eventlog, there isn't anymore.  The one line summary has the error number, the title "Windows Logon service failed" and datetime.  The content of the message is the sentence above.